# Difficulty prioritizing functions from one class to another

Tags: javascript, validation

I want make a form validation. I create a validation methods file:

ValidationMethods.js

```
export class ValidationMethods {

    empty(inputName, errorMessage) {
        let validation = false;
        if (inputName.value === '') {
            validation = true
        }
        this.result(inputName, errorMessage, validation, 'empty-validation-class')
    }

    minimum(inputName, min, errorMessage) {
        let validation = false;
        if (0 < inputName.value.length && inputName.value.length < min) {
            validation = true
        }
        this.result(inputName, errorMessage, validation, 'min-validation-class')
    }

    maximum(inputName, max, errorMessage) {
        let validation = false;
        if (inputName.value.length > max) {
            validation = true
        }
        this.result(inputName, errorMessage, validation, 'max-validation-class')
    }

    result(inputName, errorMessage, validation, classList) {
        const className = inputName.name + '-validation'
        if (validation) {
            if (document.getElementsByClassName(className).length <= 0) {
                const error = document.createElement('div')
                error.classList.add(className, classList)
                error.innerHTML = errorMessage
                inputName.parentElement.appendChild(error)
                inputName.classList.add('validation-error')
                inputName.focus()
            }
        } else {
            if (document.getElementsByClassName(classList).length > 0) {
                document.querySelector('.' + className).remove()
                inputName.classList.remove('validation-error')
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and now I use this class in my new class:

```
connect(){
    let password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0]
    const validation = new ValidationMethods()

    password.addEventListener('focusout', () => {
        validation.minimum(password,3,'Minimum character: 3')
        validation.maximum(password,6,'Maximum character: 6')
        validation.empty(password,'The field should not be empty')
    } )
}
```

everything all right. But when the empty field should show the error that the field is empty and I add a character, the errors will be cleared and the minimum number of characters error will be displayed when I focuson and focusend the field again.
This problem is due to the priority of the field call layout, but can this prioritization be removed in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is an architectural problem. A validator shouldn't display or clear error messages, only return them. You can try redesigning your code, for example, like this:

Have the basic `Validator` class with the following minimal API

```
class Validator {
    // check whether a value is valid
    valid(value): boolean;
    // return an HTML element with an error message
    errorElement(): HTMLDivElement;
}
```

Make `Empty`, `Min`, `Max` etc extend `Validator` and create a central "controller" function which would accept an element and a list of `Validators` and perform the actual UI work:

```
function validate(inputElement, validators) {
    // code to clear error messages
    //...

    // check all validators
    let failedValidators = validators.filter(v =>
         !v.valid(inputElement.value))

    // if any of them failed, display error messages
    if (failedValidators.length) {

        let errorBox = document.createElement('div')
        failedValidators.forEach(v =>
            errorBox.appendChild(v.errorElement()))
        //etc
    }
}
```

In your event handler, invoke `validate` and give it a list of `Validator` objects:

```
password.addEventListener('focusout', event => validate(event.target, [
    new EmptyValidator(...),
    new MinValidator(...),
    new MaxValidator(...),
])
```

Comment: Thank you. Do these commands display all errors or do they appear one by one?

Comment: I want show errors like https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: this displays errors from all failed validators (`failedValidators.forEach`). You can display only the first one instead (e.g. `errorBox.append(failedValidators[0].error...`)